# compareTo, как исправить ошибку

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что compareTo закидывает самую первую строчку из файла в конец после сортировки. Так выглядит код

```
    count=0;
    for(int j=0;j<r.size();j++) {
        count++;
        for(int i=r.size()-1;i>j;i--) {
            if(r.get(i).Name.compareTo(r.get(i-1).Name)<0) {
                Collections.swap(r, i, i-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот данные которые читаются из файла:

- Black Den Alex Pon Sofia Delta Maria

Вот что компилятор выдает

- Alex Delta Den Maria Pon Sofia Black
  (Black должно идти после Alex, в сравнение делает так с каждым первым элементом)

Добавляю класс r

```
class Room {
String Name;
String Surname;
String RoomS;
int RoomN;
int RoomQ;
float cost;





Room(String Name,String Surname,String RoomS,int RoomN,int RoomQ,float cost) {
    this.Name=Name;
    this.Surname=Surname;
    this.RoomS=RoomS;
    this.RoomN=RoomN;
    this.RoomQ=RoomQ;
    this.cost=cost;

}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
```

}

А так же считывания файла

```
public static void ShowFile() throws IOException{
    if(check) {
        count=0;
        String tmp;
        String str[];
        try(BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Rooms.txt"))){
            tmp=fin.readLine();
            while(tmp!=null) {
                str=tmp.split(" ");

                int r1=Integer.parseInt(str[3]);
                int r2=Integer.parseInt(str[4]);
                float r3=Float.parseFloat(str[5]);

                r.add(new Room(str[0],str[1],str[2],r1,r2,r3));

                count++;
                tmp=fin.readLine(); 
            }
            check=false;

        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error I/O" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Данные в txt файле

```
Jack Sparow Busy 1 3 100 
Daniel BlackBeard Busy 2 3 100 
Adolf Ruzveld Busy 3 4 100 
Pētersone Ilze Busy 4 8 100 
Liepa Māra Busy 5 3 100 
No Info Free 6 4 101 
No Info Free 7 6 102
```

Comment: Может в Black первая буква русская?)

Comment: Не понимаю, вашей насмешки, но нет, могу заверить, что все буквы английского алфавита

Comment: Это было предположение, самое простое. Collection.sort() не хотите использовать?

Comment: Пробовал с ним тоже, выдает такой же результат

Comment: Значит что-то не так с исходными данными. Удалите пробелы и почистите от непечатных символов string.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", "")

Comment: На приведенном коде ошибка не воспроизводится: https://ideone.com/eck4Ro Приведите [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) с полной инициализацией `r` иначе у нас нет шансов найти проблему.

Comment: По просьбе добавил инициализацию r и класс где сохраняются данные

Comment: Что если перед сортировкой (или после считывания) вывести в консоль первый символ первого элемента: `System.out.println("First: "+r.get(0).Name.charAt(0));` ?

Comment: Ввел, как у вас,только у меня стринг, если введу чар то пустая строчка . System.out.println("First: "+r.get(0).Name); , Выдает именно первое имя.Могу еще скинуть сам файл txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предполагаю, что проблема связана с кодировкой, а конкретно с [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Это невидимый символ, который некоторые текстовые редакторы вставляют в начале файла.

Для проверки можете попробовать сразу после считывания вывести первую букву имени первой комнаты:

```
 char firstLetter = r.get(0).Name.charAt(0);
 System.out.println("First letter of the first room: \""+ firstLetter + "\"("+ ((int) firstLetter)+")");
```

Если вместо первой буквы выводится `""(65279)` то это BOM.

Попробуйте следующие решения проблемы:

- Откройте файл Rooms.txt в текстовом редакторе и попробуйте установить кодировку UTF-8 без BOM. Многие редакторы (например, Notepad++) поддерживают такую возможность.
- Удаляйте символ сразу после чтения. Например, так:

  ```
  while(tmp!=null) {
      tmp = tmp.replace("\uFEFF", "");
      ...
  ```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы решили мою проблему, которая не давала покоя на протяжение 3 дней. Вы не представляете, как я вам благодарен

Comment: @TiPSY Пожалуйста! Удачи!